# JavaScript to scale YouTube on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two YouTube iframes that I want to scale (on hover) and reveal from behind a placeholder picture (on click).  The codes are conflicting.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  To see what I'm trying to accomplish [www.vgtesting.co.nf](http://www.vgtesting.co.nf) (dog walking tab).

html

```
<div id="videoandmapwrap">
    <div id="coveragemap"><img src="photos/forrestmap.jpg" class="piccon" width="200" height="200" data-video="//www.youtube.com/embed/KT-01IRqXB4?feature=player_embedded" />
  </div><!--end coveragemap-->
  <div id="piccon"> <iframe class="piccon" width="200" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/KT-01IRqXB4?feature=player_embedded"></iframe>
  </div><!--end piccon-->
  </div><!--end videoandmapwrap-->
```

js

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//to reveal from behind placeholder picture
           $('img').click(function(){
        video = '<iframe class="piccon" width="200" height="200" src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
        $(this).replaceWith(video);
    });
//to scale up on hover
var current_h = null;
var current_w = null;

$('.piccon').hover(
    function(){
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: (current_w * 2.7), height: (current_h * 2.7)}, 900);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: current_w + 'px', height: current_h + 'px'}, 400);
    }
);
     </script>

//using event delegation
//to reveal from behind placeholder picture
           $('#videoandmapwrap').on("click","img",function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
        video = '<iframe class="piccon" width="200" height="200" src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
        $(this).replaceWith(video);  
    });
//to scale up on hover
var current_h = null;
var current_w = null;

$('#videoandmapwrap').on("hover","img", function(event){
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: (current_w * 2.7), height: (current_h * 2.7)}, 900);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width: current_w + 'px', height: current_h + 'px'}, 400);
    }
  event.preventDefault();
);
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. After replacing the image, the new video doesn't obey your `.hover`? This is the expected behavior since you're not using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) (solve by binding `.hover` on a parent element).

Comment: Conflictions can be ignored with **preventDefault**

Comment: yes, after i click on the image it no longer obeys the .hover.

Comment: I followed your link but I must be doing something wrong

Comment: i've added my attempt at using event delegation, I applied it to the click snippet successfully, but broke the code when applying it to the hover...